# How to get the specific object inside the function using Python?

Tags: python, function, object

I have a python code below. I would like to get the value of one of the object inside the function. For the example I want to get the value of this `tmpdict["CpuType"] = cpu.Name` in another process function.
How do I get it with this function. Thank you

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI()

def printCPU():
    tmpdict = {}
    tmpdict["CpuCores"] = 0
    for cpu in c.Win32_Processor():
        tmpdict["cpuid"] = cpu.ProcessorId.strip()
        tmpdict["CpuType"] = cpu.Name
        tmpdict['systemName'] = cpu.SystemName
        try:
            tmpdict["CpuCores"] = cpu.NumberOfCores
        except:
            tmpdict["CpuCores"] += 1
        tmpdict["CpuClock"] = cpu.MaxClockSpeed
        tmpdict['DataWidth'] = cpu.DataWidth
    print(tmpdict)
    return tmpdict
printCPU()
```

Comment: Aren't you returning `tmpdict`? It contains the key `"CpuType"` so you can pass it to another function.

Comment: No, I don't. I only need the value of `tmpdict["CpuType"] = cpu.Name` to process it in another function @ccarstens

Comment: What happens on the last line then?

Comment: if I add `printCPU()` ini the last line, then it will print all the value which are `cpuid, CpuType, systemName` . but my expectation I need to read the value separately. @ccarstens

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the `CpuType` value in `tmpdict`:

```python
def printCPU():
    ...

def otherFunction(cpuType):
    # do something with cpuType
    ...

cpuValues = printCPU()

otherFunction(vpuValues['CpuType'])
```